# Registration in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, registration

I'm having an issue with my registration, whatever i do it is always telling me that user already exists, though it does not show any error, css is not included here, and using mysql_query is prohibited(homework).

```
<?PHP
include "config.php";
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['nick']) && isset($_POST['heslo']) && 
isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['datnar']) && ($_POST["jmeno"]) &&     ($_POST["prijmeni"]) && isset($_POST['Typ_Kontaktu']))  

{
try
{   
    $email = ($_POST['email']);
    $datnar = ($_POST['datnar']);
    $nick = ($_POST['nick']);
    if($_POST['heslo'] == $_POST['heslo1'])
      {
        $heslo = ($_POST['heslo']);
      }
    $jmeno = ($_POST['jmeno']);
    $typk = ($_POST['Typ_Kontaktu']);
    $prijmeni = ($_POST['prijmeni']);
    $db->query("INSERT INTO tblosoba(`NICK`, `HESLO`, `EMAIL`, `DATNAR`, `JMENO`, `PRIJMENI`, `TYPKONTAKTU_ID`) VALUES ($nick, '$heslo', $email, $datnar, $jmeno, $prijmeni, $typk)");
    echo "Registrace dokončena.";
}
catch(Exception $e)
  {
    echo "Uživatel existuje";
  }
}
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
if (empty($_POST["nick"]))
{echo "Přihlašovací jméno je vyžadováno!<br>";}
if (empty($_POST["heslo"]))
{echo "Heslo je vyžadováno!<br>";}  
if (empty($_POST["email"]))
{echo "Email je vyžadován!<br>";}
if (empty($_POST["datnar"]))
{echo "Datum narození je vyžadováno! ";}
}
$ssql="COUNT(USER_ID) FROM tblosoba";
?>
<html>
<form id="frm" name="frm" method="POST" action="<?PHP $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<fieldset>
<legend><h3>Registrace Uživatele</h3></legend>
<label for='jmeno'>Vaše jméno: </label>
<input type='text' name='jmeno'><br>
<label for='prijmeni'>Vaše Přijmení: </label>
<input type='text' name='prijmeni'><br>
<label for='nick'>Váš nick: </label>
</span><input type="text" name="nick"><br>
<label for='heslo' >Vaše heslo: </label>
<input type="password" name="heslo"><br>
<label for='heslo1' >Ověření hesla: </label>
<input type="password" name="heslo1"><br>
<label for='email' >Váš email: </label>
<input type="text" name="email"><br>
<label for='datnar' >Vaše datum narození: </label>
<input type="text" name="datnar"><br>
<label for='tk'>Váš typ kontaktu: </label>
<SELECT name='Typ_Kontaktu'>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbltypkon";
$result = $db->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {                                                 
    echo "<option value='".$row['ID_TYPKON']."'>".$row['TYPKONTAKTU']."</option>";
  }
?>
</SELECT>
<button type="submit" value="odeslat" name="odeslat">Odeslat</button>
</fieldset>
<h6><sup><?PHP echo "*Datum narození zadávejte ve formátu RRRRMMDD bez jakýchkoliv znaků!"         ?></sup></h6>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you translate the error for us? ;)

Comment: it just says that User already exists, even though he does not :/

Comment: Sidenote: Only one value has quotes around them `VALUES ($nick, '$heslo', $email, $datnar, $jmeno, $prijmeni, $typk)")` Change to `VALUES ('$nick', '$heslo', '$email', '$datnar', '$jmeno', '$prijmeni', '$typk')")` @user3478311

Comment: it still says the same :/

Comment: What is the Exception thas is being thrown? It's probably a `PDOException`, which tells you a lot about the error. Also, please show a query which is filled in. Try binding parameters instead of adding them into your string.

Comment: Instead of `echo "Uživatel existuje";` use `echo $e->getMessage();`